# python twitter bot with selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

**Hi, how are you? I'm making a twitter bot with selenium but it always throws an error with the chromedriver, any solution? Thank you**

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

class TwitterBot():
    def __init__(self, username, password):

self.browser = webdriver.Chrome("C:\Users\sfdxs\Downloads\chromedriver")
    self.username = username
    self.password = password

def signIn(self):
    self.browser.get("https://twitter.com/login")
    time.sleep(5)

usernameInput = self.browser.find_element_by_name("session[username_or_email]"")
passwordInput = self.browser.find_element_by_name("session[password]")
    usernameInput.send_keys(self.username)
    passwordInput.send_keys(self.password)
    passwordInput.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
    time.sleep(5)

def TweetSomething(self):
    tweet = self.browser.find_element_by_xpath('''//*[@id='react-root']/div/div/div[2]/main/div/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div[1]/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div''')
    tweet.send_keys("""Hello World""")
    tweet.send_keys(Keys.COMMAND, Keys.ENTER)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    username = input("Enter Username")
    password = input("Enter passoword")
    t = TwitterBot(username, password)
    t.signIn()
    t.TweetSomething()
```

**I tried anyway but I can't find a solution :/**

Comment: explore their API if you really want to make a twitter bot.

Comment: also: post the error you're experiencing so we can help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can instead use the Twitter API with the `requests` library (It's `pip install requests` I think).

Here's the link to the documentation: https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api

The error is that on the line

`self.browser = webdriver.Chrome("C:\Users\sfdxs\Downloads\chromedriver")`

you forgot to add `.exe` so the line should be

`self.browser = webdriver.Chrome("C:\Users\sfdxs\Downloads\chromedriver.exe")`

instead.

Also, Twitter probably has a `reCAPTCHA`(something that prevents bots) on the login page so I suggest that you use their API.

Comment: while this is good advice, and probably the direction they should go, it's not actually the right answer to the question.

Comment: @DMart I _did_ explain that the error is the missing `.exe` in the line `self.browser = webdriver.Chrome("C:\Users\sfdxs\Downloads\chromedriver")`.